# Print matrix secondary diagonal in C++ with for loop?

Tags: c++, matrix, diagonal

I have a simple program in which I want to print all of the elements in the secondary diagonal of the matrix - these are the numbers 5,9,13,-21,12 but the program does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 5
int a[SIZE][SIZE]={
{1,2,3,4,5},
{6,7,8,9,10},
{11,12,13,14,15},
{100,-21,-70,345,77},
{12,17,765,98,55}
};

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)//The first index increases
for(int k=5;k>0;k--)//The second index decreases
cout<<a[i][k]<<endl;//Printing the element
```

Comment: Some comments about your code: If you use something like SIZE, then use is consistently. It should say `for(int i=0;i<SIZE;...`. If you'd changed SIZE to 4 later on, your for loop would iterate to a wrong bound. Also, you should always use indentation. And I recommend always using the brackets, even if you have only one command - if you add another command later on when you have forgotten that you omitted the brackets, stuff goes bad.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a second [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for). You can do it using only one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    std::cout << a[i][SIZE - i - 1] << ' ';
}
```

This way you have two indexes going opposite ways using a single `for` loop.

Comment: @Y.Ivanov In other words, a diagonal is 1-dimentional, so iterating it only involves a single loop. You wouldn't try iterating a column with two loops.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you did

```
for (k=5; k>0; k--)
```

but there is no  `a[0][5]`

the last element in the first row is     `a[0][4]`
so your array should start from 4 and go down to 0

```
for (k=4; k>=0; k--)
```

Btw it can be done with just 1 loop.

For every element of the second diagonal, the sum of the indexes is 4.

```
0+4=4
1+3=4
2+2=3
3+1=4
4+0=4
```

so you can write it as       `a[i][4-i]`

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) 
cout<<a[i][4-i]<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing in this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    cout << a[i][4-i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did I get a minus one when mine was the very first correct answer?